# JavaScript - Rock Paper Scissors Game

Tags: javascript, game, rock-paper-scissors

I built a simple console version of the rock paper scissors game. I would love to get some constructive criticism!

**Questions**

1. How could I code this in an object-oriented way?
2. Did my code follow the DRY principle?

**Link to code**

Repl: https://repl.it/@antgotfan/CrowdedGreenFlatassembler

```
        var moves, result, images, relativePath, playerSelection, computerSelection;

    moves = {
        rock: 0, 
        paper: 1, 
        scissors: 2,
    };

    function init() {

        result = {
            player: 0,
            tie: 0,
            computer: 0
        };
    }

    init();

    function convertMoves() {
        // when any rock paper scissor button is clicked 

        // then return that string into the moves object 

        // return a number corresponding to the handsign.
        playerSelection = prompt("Please choose rock, paper, or scissors!");
        return moves[playerSelection];    
    }

    function computerPlay() {
        var movesValues = Object.values(moves);
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * movesValues.length);
        return movesValues[random];
    } 

    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
        computerSelection = computerPlay();
        playerSelection = convertMoves();

        var processResult = (3 + computerSelection - playerSelection) % 3;

        if (!processResult) {
            ++result.tie;
            console.log('tie');
        } else if (1 === processResult) {
            ++result.computer;
            console.log('Computer won');
        } else {
            ++result.player;
            console.log('Player won');
        }

        return result;
    }

    function game() {
        for (var perRound = 1; perRound < 5; perRound++) {
            playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
        }
    }

    game();
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite answer your questions, but still hopefully helpful.

`var perRound = 1; perRound < 5; perRound++` only executes four times; the fifth execution is coming from the last line of your program. It's customary to use `i` when simply doing something multiple times, and to start with `0` such as: `var i = 0; i < 5; i++`. Then remove that extra `playRound` at the end so you still have five rounds.

I would rename `convertMoves` to `playerMove` to better describe what it does instead of how it does it.

`playRound` isn't using its arguments. So you can change the first few lines to:

```
    function playRound() {
        var computerSelection = computerPlay();
        var playerSelection = convertMoves();
```

You might play with changing `moves` to an array and see if you like it better as `moves = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];`. This will require several other changes to how you use it but I think it'll read easier in the end.

Just as a matter of style, put the `++` after the variable except for the rare times when you really need the other behavior.

Again, hope this helps.

Edit: I see now why you have the extra `playRound` at the end. But `result` is already global so you can simply end with `console.log(result)` instead of returning it from `playRound` each time.

Comment: This was really helpful! Thank you Nathan.